# Building textarea with tags/variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an easy way an end user can generate "pseudo-code" on how to generate a final string. I think it would be easier if I gave an example.

I have the following variables:

- `Round`
- `Game`
- `Wins`
- `Losses`
- `Player`
- `Opponent`
- `Rating`

In the back end of my application, I'm doing this all manually.

```
echo Player + " is currently playing " + Opponent + ". Round: " + Round + ", Game: " + Game;
if ( Wins > Losses ) {
   echo " (Up a Game)";
} else if ( Wins < Losses ) {
   echo " (Down a game)";
}
```

What I'd like to ultimately do is give control to the end user of how this string is being displayed. I'd like them to add variables where they want, as well as add if/else statements.

I looked a bit into [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) and [select2](https://select2.github.io/), and they seem to be on the right track of what I'm looking for, but doesn't really contain any if/else functionality I need. Something I have used in the past is [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/) which does contain if/else logic, but this can be a bit complex to the end user. Does anyone have any other recommendations of javascript/jQuery plugins/scripts I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: You could do this via a php file that searches for and replaces keywords with the values you wanted. To use this set up an ajax call to get it dynamically!

Comment: Then what exactly are you looking for? Are you looking for an existing plugin? Do you need kind of a compiler?

Comment: Blockly is an example of something that may be what I'm looking for. Not too worried about the logistics of compiling/getting it to the string, more a nice view for the end user to generate these strings. If there is an existing plugin or one that I can extend functionality too quite easily, that is also something that would be helpful. Any links to websites/plugins/apps, all would be useful.

Comment: Two comments - pseudo - sudo is a linux "super-user do" command, and standard practice is to name variables with a lower case first letter - to differentiate from classes which normally start upper-case :-P

Comment: Funny story @Rycochet (I actually googled this, and found the correct spelling). Apparently as I was editing, and going through the view iterations of this question before I posted it, it reverted back to the original spelling (Oops!). Now sudo make me a sandwich ;P

Comment: Maybe you didn't have permission to change the spelling...? (sorry lol)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use selectize and add some nice css features. E.g. you could use the data-value selector

```
[data-value="if"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to distinguish if/else tags from other tags. Next you could use the adjacent sibling css selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) to find the next tag after an if statement to mark this aswell

```
[data-value="if"] + div {
    background-color: anything;
}
```

Moreover you can also distinguish variables using the same technique. Later, a parser could parse the if/else statements using regexp or whatever suits you best.

Someone could then write something like

```
[Player][" is currently playing "][Opponent][". Round: "][Round]
[", Game: "][Game][if][Wins>Losses][" (Up a Game)"][else][" (Down a game)"]
```

where the brackets indicate "tags". Your parser then should tread tags with quotations "" as string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use php to look for key words in a string and replace them with the stuff you actually want!

```
$s="Player is currently playing Opponent [ROUND], Game: Game";
$s = str_replace("[ROUND]", "Round: $Round", $s );
```

For example look for [ROUND] and replace it with your desired content.

Then with out reloading the page, use ajax to call the php file to do the work for you!

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but I'm not looking for the end solution to replace the variables. I'm looking for a nice interface where they can "plug and play" the variables into the textbox (Or textarea), and pass that information to the server.

Comment: @FrankerZ You need to pass the rendered log to the server or the pseudo code that the players type?

Comment: I'm not looking for code at all. I'm looking for a solution to generate some type of code which I will then pass to the server side to generate the strings needed for output (Replacing variables, parsing if/else statements, etc...). For example: [Markup.js](https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js/) is a great tool that I can use to template something together (I can even build the parser server side), it's having the client make the template in an easy way via a GUI. That GUI is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a custom client side parsing of text, maybe this will help you.

```js
var keywords = {
  
  Round: 'red',
  Game: 'green',
  if: 'blue',
  else: 'blue',
  then: 'blue'

}

$('#input').keyup(function(){

  var parsedInputTags = $(this).val().split(/[\[\]]/);
  
  $('#output').html('');
  
  parsedInputTags.forEach(function(text){
  
    if(text in keywords){
    
      $('#output').append('<span data-tag="' + text + '" class="tag-' + keywords[text] + '">' + text + '</span>');
    
    }
    else $('#output').append('<span>' + text + '</span>');
  
  });

});
```

```css
.tag-red {
  color: red;
}

.tag-green {
  color: green;
}

[data-tag="if"] + span {
  color: cyan;
}

.tag-blue {
  color: blue;
}

textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#output { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input" placeholder="Type this: This is game [Game] in round [Round]. [if] something > smth [then] type this [else] type that"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```